# MaterialUI text fade with useEffect and setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, setinterval, fade

I am using MaterialUI's Fade component to simulate a text carousel that comes in and out according to the provided array in a prop called dataArray. I am using setIntervals to keep switching the boolean of the Fade and to change the array info. The main problem is that **the text switches mid transition after the first iteration of the fade**. What I am trying to achieve is a smooth fade transition and info switching loop according to the provided array while the text is hidden. I tried using async, but that does not seem to work on setIntevals.

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Paper, Fade } from '@material-ui/core';
import './FadeCarousel.css';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  paper: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    color: '#f4dfc0',
    padding: '1vw 0vw 1vw 0vw',
    fontFamily: 'Chenier',
    fontSize: '2vw',
  },
}));

const FadeCarousel = ({ dataArray }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);
  const [carouselData, setCarousel] = React.useState(dataArray[0]);

  useEffect(() => {
    var count = 0;
    // Interval Fade
    setInterval(() => {
      setChecked((prev) => !prev);
    }, 5000);
    // Interval Change Data
    setInterval(() => {
      if (count == dataArray.length - 1) {
        count = 0;
      } else count++;
      setCarousel(dataArray[count]);
    }, 8000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Fade
        in={checked}
        timeout={{
          enter: 3000,
          exit: 3000,
        }}
      >
        <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paper}>
          {carouselData}
        </Paper>
      </Fade>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FadeCarousel;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your count should change after the `Fade` goes through its `exit` cycles to have it change at the moment that the fade is on its "dark" phase.

That means that your timings should be as follows:

`intervalFade = X`

`intervalChangeData = 2*X`

Fade `timeout = {enter: 2*X, exit: 2*X}`

Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-lake-qtr16?file=/src/App.js:0-1323)

Code result:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Paper, Fade } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  paper: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    color: '#f4dfc0',
    padding: '1vw 0vw 1vw 0vw',
    fontFamily: 'Chenier',
    fontSize: '2vw',
  },
}));

const FadeCarousel = ({ dataArray }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);
  const [carouselData, setCarousel] = React.useState(dataArray[0]);

  const fadeTime = 1000

  useEffect(() => {
    var count = 0;
    // Interval Fade
    setInterval(() => {
      setChecked((prev) => !prev);
    }, fadeTime);
    // Interval Change Data
    setInterval(() => {
      if (count == dataArray.length - 1) {
        count = 0;
      } else count++;
      setCarousel(dataArray[count]);
    }, fadeTime*2);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Fade
        in={checked}
        timeout={{
          enter: fadeTime*2,
          exit: fadeTime*2,
        }}
      >
        <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paper}>
          {carouselData}
        </Paper>
      </Fade>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FadeCarousel;
```

Comment: Actually, the text transition is still viewable when it is about to vanish... How do I improve this? Try it on fadeTime = 5000

Comment: Changing the value of `fadeTime` without a page refresh will change the `timeout` prop value, but not the values within the useEffect block (since this runs only on first render, but not re-render) - this causes the timing to get out of sync.

Comment: I did refresh the webpage and even restarted th dev server, however there is still this 1 moment where you can see the words changing. I used black background and white color text with this. Try to set the fadeTime to 5000, youll see what I mean

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue on code sandbox at 5000ms, but your environment may be rendering in a slightly different way.  

The way timings are implemented are pretty fragile.  We need a way to ensure that all the timings are maintained even during re-renders.  I'll need to think on this a bit...